# Find weak_ptr in vector

Tags: c++, find, smart-pointers, weak-references

I am trying to find weak_ptr in vector. I am using lambda expression as a third parameter to find but I can't understand why this code is not compiled:

```c++
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Car>> cars;

std::shared_ptr<Car> lambo = std::make_shared<Car>();
std::weak_ptr<Car> wPtr(lambo);
cars.emplace_back(lambo);

const auto pos = std::find(cars.begin(), cars.end(), [&wPtr](const std::weak_ptr<Car>& ptr1) {
    return ptr1.lock() == wPtr.lock();
});

if (pos != cars.end())
    cout << "Not found!" << endl;
```

Maybe someone could point me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please get into the habit of submitting [MCVE]s. Seven years is long enough to learn that skill! See my answer for how yours becomes an MCVE, and consider editing your question to uphold our standards of quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure you meant [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (which takes a predicate), not `std::find` (which takes a *value*).

Also fixing your conditional at the end, and adding appropriate boilerplate, we get:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Car {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Car>> cars;

    std::shared_ptr<Car> lambo = std::make_shared<Car>();
    std::weak_ptr<Car> wPtr(lambo);
    cars.emplace_back(lambo);

    const auto pos = std::find_if(cars.begin(), cars.end(), [&wPtr](const std::weak_ptr<Car>& ptr1) {
        return ptr1.lock() == wPtr.lock();
    });

    if (pos == cars.end())
        std::cout << "Not found!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;
}

// Output: Found!
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39dca9c285dd6031))

Comment: Thanks, yes my mistake.

Comment: Note that if `wPtr` is expired/null, then this method will return an iterator to the first expired/null weak pointer in the vector. If that's not desirable, you would have to add an extra condition.